# What does single dash mean in curl command?

Tags: curl

curl commands like:

Continue downloading a document:

```
    curl -C - -o file ftp://ftp.server.com/path/file
```

Continue uploading a document(*1):

```
    curl -C - -T file ftp://ftp.server.com/path/file
```

I mean "-" between "-C" and "-o/-T".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is part of the `-C` option. From the curl man page:

> Use "-C -" to tell curl to automatically find out where/how to resume the transfer. It then uses the given output/input files to figure that  out.